# Copiar valores de un DataGridView a un nuevo DataTable para poder ser comparados

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente conflicto, por medio de varios objetos y *queries* estoy consultando 4 bases de datos diferentes que en conjunto cargan con información a un `DataGrid`,este `DataGrid` a su vez debe alimentar a otra tabla con la información que contiene, el problema esta cuando intento comparar el contenido del *grid* con un `DataTable` que consulta la tabla final que deberá almacenar la información del *grid*, ¿alguien qué me de una idea de cómo hacer dicha comparación? Gracias por su valiosa ayuda.

```
/*Variables Globales*/
bool existe = false;
string fechaI = dtpInicial.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
string fechaF = dtpFinal.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
string estaciones = cmbEstacion.SelectedValue.ToString().Substring(0, cmbEstacion.SelectedValue.ToString().IndexOf('~'));
/*Objetos*/
Datos.Corresponsalia objCorresponsalia = new Datos.Corresponsalia();
DataTable dtCorresponsalias = new DataTable();
dtCorresponsalias = objCorresponsalia.ConsultaCorresponsalia(fechaI, fechaF, estaciones);
if (dtCorresponsalias==dgvRegistros.DataSource)
{
    existe = true;
    if (existe)
    {
        objCorresponsalia.BorrarDuplicados(fechaI, fechaF, estaciones);
    }
    else
    {
            if (dgvRegistros.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvRegistros.Rows)
                {
                    objCorresponsalia.InsertaFilasDataGrid(fechaI, fechaF, estaciones);

                    objValidacion.MostrarAviso("Cargando registros en la Base de Datos por favor espere un Momento", false, lblAviso);
                }
                objValidacion.MostrarAviso("Carga exitosa en la Base de Datos", false, lblAviso);
            }
            else
            {
                objValidacion.MostrarAviso("No se encontraron registros para guardar", true, lblAviso);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: necesitas comparar la row del foreach y si existe no realizarias el insert ?

Comment: lo que no veo es porque dentro del foreach no usas en ningun momento el variable "row" se supone que a InsertaFilasDataGrid() deberias pasarle los datos que obtienes del grid

Answer (score 1):

Si la idea es validar sobre el datatable podrias ayudarte con linq, o sea algo como ser

```
bool existe = dtCorresponsalias.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                                .Any(x=> x.Cells["NombreCampo"].Value.ToString() == valor)

if(!existe)
{
    //aqui insertas
}
```

con esto aplica una busqueda sobre los datos en memoria que estan en el datatable cargados

Comment: eres una leyenda, Saludos

Comment: La idea es que,  si la tabla final esta vacía que se realice el insert, y si el contenido del datagridview es igual al contenido de la tabla final, elimine todos los registros en la tabla final e inserte los nuevos.

Comment: pero si la idea es volcar los datos porque simplemente no realizas un DELETE de todos los registros de esa tabla y luego insertas el contenido del grid, por lo que entiendo no necesitas validar